# set hive configuration variable from query

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible to set hive configuration variable from query ?

For example I have a query:

```
select name from stg_log;
```

and I want to store 'name' into

```
hiveconf:name
```

varible.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using bash  to execute your queries you can do something like

```
  name=$(hive -S -e "select name from stg_log;")
```

and then pass this variable to your next query as a param

```
  hive -d name=$name -f new_query.hql
```

in this hql file you would be able to use this variable as

```
  ${name}
```